# What is the value range of the log level parameter --v of kube-apiserver?

Tags: kubernetes, verbosity, kube-apiserver

I want to change kube-apiserver log level use --v parameter , I checked all the documents, and none of them gave the value range of this parameter.

Check the code, the value is int32 type, I tried to fill in 0, 1, 2, and even 9999, all can pass the verification and start kube-apiserver normally.

So I want to know what is the value range of this parameter.Is the value 9999 really meaningful?

Answer (score 1):

9999 isn't a valid value.

[image: Table]

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.8/rest_api/editing-kubelet-log-level-verbosity.html#log-verbosity-descriptions_editing-kubelet-log-level-verbosity

https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-instrumentation/logging.md

I suggest not to increase the verbosity of the logs in the production environment (activate them only if necessary, otherwise you may have performance problems).

Comment: But according to my test, there is no problem if the value is greater than 8, and the program will run normally.
And more log information will be printed.